# Pandas equivalent to calculate False Positive Rate

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` from a ML classifier that has the following fields `userid`, `classifier_score`, `truth`. I want to calculate the false positive rate per userid at a threshold of 0.62. `classifier_score` ranges in the data go from 0.1999 to a 0.89. Right now, I use a series of conditions and create a new column `col` that states whether if the relationship between truth and classifier score is a false positive, false negative, true positive or true negative

`df['col'] = df.apply(condition, axis=1)`

Then I store the the unique userids in a list

`unique_users = df.user.unique().tolist()`
Then I loop through each one to calculate False positive score.

```
fpr_dict = {}
for id in user_ids:
   fn, tn, fp, tp = 0, 0, 0, 0 
   elems = df[df.userid==id].tolist()
   for elem in col:
       if elem == 'fn': fn += 1
       elif elem == 'fp': fp += 1
       elif elem == 'tp': tp += 1
       elif elem == 'tn': tn += 1
   try:
      fpr = fp / (fp + tn) 
   except ZeroDivisionError:
      fpr = 0.0
   fpr_dict[id] = fpr
```

Is there a better way of doing this with just pandas functions?
Note: I initialize fn, tn, fp, tp to 0 because some user ids might not have all 4 of them, they will have some combination of the 4

Edit: Dataframe

```
userid | classifier_score | truth  | col 
0001      0.6721            1        TP
0001      0.2918            1        FP
0001      0.1236            0        TN
.
.
.
0064      0.7168            0        FN
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the dataframe you are using?

Comment: please see [ask] and [mcve] updated tour question with a sample of your input and expected dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test it with an actual dataframe, maybe try this

```
th = 0.62
predicted_pos = df['classifier_score'] > th

userid_group = df.groupby('userid', sort=False)

userid_count = userid_group.size()

df['fp'] = predicted_pos & (df['truth'] == 0)
fpr = userid_group['fp'].sum() / userid_count
```

if you want a dictionary, you can put `dict(fpr)` in the end

---

Edit: As OP pointed out, fpr = fp/(fp + tn), the calculation should be:

```
th = 0.62
predicted_pos = df['classifier_score'] > th

userid_group = df.groupby('userid', sort=False)

df['fp'] = predicted_pos & (df['truth'] == 0)
df['tn'] = df['truth'] == 0

fp = userid_group['fp'].sum()
tn = userid_group['tn'].sum()
fpr =  fp / (fp + tn)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is on the right track but the divisor is wrong at the end. for the full positive rate you need to divide the number of false positives by either the total number of negatives or the sum of the false positives and true negatives.

Comment: Modified your code to make it work for me though. Thanks! @Sam

Comment: np, thanks for pointing out the mistake, i just make an edit.